# Prevent duplicate values in CRUD app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-redux, crud

There is a simple CRUD app (BE express and FE react-redux) where form values are being added to `mongodb`, schema below:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

var Schema = mongoose.Schema({
  createdAt:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  carNumber: { type : String , index: { unique: true }},
  carOwner: String
});

export default mongoose.model('Car', Schema);
```

`index: { unique: true }` prevents from adding same `carNumber` values by bringing [error](https://i.gyazo.com/e4b0d4d2f177cca54337b537804becb7.png)

Cars are selected with dispatcher function in `carActions.js`:

```
//Async action
export const fetchCars = () => {
  // Returns a dispatcher function
  // that dispatches an action at later time
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchCarsRequest());
    // Returns a promise
    return fetch(apiUrl)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response.json().then(data => {
            dispatch(fetchCarsSuccess(data.cars, data.message));
          })
        }
        else {
          response.json().then(error => {
            dispatch(fetchCarsFailed(error));
          })
        }
      })
  }
}
```

and rendered in `Cars` component:

```
render() {
    const carState = this.props.mappedCarState;
    const cars = carState.cars;
return (

<tbody>
      {cars.map((car, i) => <tr key={i}>
         <td>{car.carNumber} {car.carOwner}</td>
         <td><Button onClick={() => this.deleteCar(car)} ></Button></td>         
   </tr>)
</tbody>
}
```

I am very news to this kind of wiring, may someone suggest on how I should prevent error and return notification?

I could miss some important information, here is [link](https://github.com/romran/crud-add-car-app) to rep.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider indexing carNumber, which ensures that MongoDB will prevent duplicate values in the field.

```
db.<collection name>.createIndex({carNumber:1},{unique:true})
```

Comment: it is, but also it brings error when adding same value. Take a look at the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `unique` index for `carNumber`  in your schema.

This will make sure that no duplicate values are added in collection for `carNumber`

```
 carNumber: { type : String , index: { unique: true }}
```

Comment: many thanks for suggestion, updated schema catch duplicate value and brings error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'carNumber' of undefined` May you know, if it is possible to return notification instead of error?

Comment: it is not because of this index. How are you selecting the cars list from db ?

Comment: Match your syntax with `<ul>
    {todos.map((todo, index) => (
      <Todo key={index} {...todo} onClick={() => onTodoClick(index)} />
    ))}
  </ul>`

Comment: Tried your solution but it brings error: https://i.gyazo.com/87929aaee5725ff0b9785c218730aaf3.png
 have updated question, may you know if it is the correct function for selecting cars from db?